# Strange behaviour of dc power supply unit- Voltage increases as loading is increased. What could be the reason?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

I was testing an SMPS converter( efficiency test) with varying load current. The input voltage  to the converter is held constant by a standard dc power supply unit in lab.

As a general trend , I see the input voltage ( from dc power supply unit) dips slightly as loading is increased.
 But for few readings I see an increase in input voltage( from previous reading) as loading is increased.

Is there any valid reason for this behaviour? We have checked multiple times and see this behaviour for couple of readings.

Edit: We got the expected results while performing the same test next day.:)

Comment: Can you share the exact readings, or at least some details so that we have a sense of how large the fluctuations are? Additionally, details about the SMPS converter (model, topology, etc) would probably be helpful.

Comment: What instruments are you using to measure the input and output voltages and currents, and how are they connected? Are you making all 4 measurements simultaneously, or are you disconnecting the instrument from one location to measure the next location?

Comment: Sounds like the voltage feedback loop isn't doing what it's supposed to.  Almost like there's a dead zone.

Comment: is the load linear? or non-linear?

Comment: An SMPS transfers pulses of energy from the input to an output, and some feedback system decides how many pulses to transfer per second based on the output voltage or current. It's not inconceivable that the feedback system could overcompensate slightly sometimes.

Comment: _"I see the **input voltage ( from dc power supply unit)** dips slightly as loading is increased. But for few readings I see an increase in **input** voltage"_ - this could be caused by the SMPS _or_ the lab power supply.  Please tell us the SMPS input and output voltages and **currents**.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is 
Input **ESR  [Ω] = ΔV / ΔI**  vs. Power Out [W]

The fact that over small range the efficiency jumps and what was a monotonic positive ESR to a negative ESR may or may not be of interest to the design from efficiency, ripple or resonance point of view , but begs the questions about your missing details.

So what can you define about the design and test process.?

Input impedance is related to the V² ratio  like turns ratio , N² on a transformer. But there may be more complex mode switching occurring or spurious resonance.

Show your data with Vin/Iin,  ripple vs Output, ripple or whatever spec it is not meeting.